# Maintaining current indentation in a custom MVC HTML-extension helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have the following custom extension to `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<T>`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString WrapInDiv<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, String text)  
{
    String htmlRaw = String.Format("<div>{0}</div>", text);
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(htmlRaw); // For formatting
    return new MvcHtmlString(xDoc.ToString());
{
```

..and I use it in this view snippet:

```
<span>
    @Html.WrapInDiv("sasuage")
</span>
```

The result would be as follows:

```
<span> 
    <div>
    Sausage
</div>
</span>
```

because the `XDocument` writer obviously don't know that we're already in a section with four characters indentation. Any way I can fix this so that my HTML helpers print perfectly indented multi-line HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to keep the indentation proper? Browsers do not care, and it's a lot of work and a very hard problem to resolve, especially when you are doing helpers and do not have the whole context.

The best way, if you really, really need visually formatted outputs, is to do it globally for each page generated with an HTTP Module that intercept answers and maybe one of the .Net port of [Html Tidy](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tidy).

```
public class HtmlTidyModule: IHttpModule
{
    private EventHandler ReleaseRequestStateEvent = null;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ReleaseRequestStateEvent != null)
            context.ReleaseRequestState -= ReleaseRequestStateEvent;
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        ReleaseRequestStateEvent = new EventHandler(event_ReleaseRequestState); 
        context.ReleaseRequestState += ReleaseRequestStateEvent;
    }

    void event_ReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        // You need to implement HtmlTidyFilter to handle the response
        app.Response.Filter = new HtmlTidyFilter(app.Response.Filter)
    }
}
```

But you must ask yourself, do you really want to do this?? Most integrated HTML viewers/inspectors in browsers does this already (F12 in chrome/FF I believe).

Comment: I like your solution and I also appreciate you question my motives. I wanted to tidy it because it's easier to read the generated source when I'm debugging (View Source in IE, Ctrl+U). But then again, as you say, the debugging tools have built in source navigation and tidying, so maybe I should focus on using the tools better instead.